# JDK libs rather than Android SDK libs

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I use Android studio for my Android code base and my code uses `ZipInputStream.java`, which is provided by both **Android SDK and JDK**. It doesn't matter which version of SDK or JDK it is.

Strange thing is when I run my apk on Android-M and lower devices and emulators, the version of the above mentioned class comes from SDK but on Android N emulator, while using the same apk, `ZipInputStream.java` comes from the JDK.

How can I force Android N to use the classes from SDK by default and not JDK?

*Please note that I have tried this by building the apk by using api 23 and 24 as both target and compile sdk versions, 23.x and 24.x versions for both build tools and support-v4. I even tried by using both JDK 7 and 8. It seems there's something with the Android N OS in how it chooses JDK classes over SDK classes that I might be missing. Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: *the version of the above mentioned class comes from SDK* no ... if you run app on device/emulator it use ZipInputStream implementation from runtime library of the device/emulator ... also how did you "check" it?

Comment: I confirmed by placing breakpoints in both versions of the file. Also, for Android-N it behaves exactly like the JDK version of the files expects it to. For <N, it behaves according to the SDK version of file.
About the runtime library, does Android N emulator have a runtime that uses JDK version of class? Because Android M emulator uses the class from SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but on Android N emulator, while using the same apk, ZipInputStream.java comes from the JDK

The device/emulator always uses the `ZipInputStream` implementation that is on the device/emulator. There is no Java source code on the device/emulator.

Now, Android 7.0/N shifted a lot of `java.*` and `javax.*` classes from the original, Apache Harmony-based editions [to ones that are based on the OpenJDK](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/25/watch-out-openjdk-differences-android-n.html). I do not know whether `ZipInputStream` changed or not.

> How can I force Android N to use the classes from SDK by default and not JDK?

You don't. The implementation of framework classes, including `java.*` and `javax.*` classes, comes from the device/emulator, not your app.

On the whole, the migration from Harmony to the OpenJDK [has been fairly smooth](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/19/magical-openjdk-migration.html). If you are running into compatibility issues, where `ZipInputStream` no longer behaves as it did, create a reproducible test case and [file an issue](http://b.android.com).

Comment: Thanks. pretty elaborate answer. Wonder if people down-voting my question knew this. Had they known they'd have commented. Thanks again.